# Spring RequestMapping wrong view path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with mappings and ModelAndView. All simply mappings like "/login" works but I have problem with:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/note/{noteId:[\\d]+}")
public class NoteController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView note(@PathVariable String noteId, HttpSession session) {
    // not important code
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("note");
    return modelAndView;
  }
}
```

I have an error here and path: `/note/WEB-INF/views/jsp/note.jsp`.

I wanted to get `WEB-INF/views/jsp/note.jsp` and I have similar path in other ModelAndViews (without prefix).

My configuration:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`.

Comment: What's a difference?

Comment: `@RestController` returns everything as a response body, it automatically returns your `ModelAndView` as JSON or XML. `@Controller` does proper view resolution. Also your prefix should be `/WEB-INF/views/jsp/`. Include the leading `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've started using Spring 3 days ago and nothing is obvious for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M. Deinum solved this problem.

> Replace @RestController with @Controller
>
> @RestController returns everything as a response body, it automatically returns your ModelAndView as JSON or XML. @Controller does proper view resolution. Also your prefix should be /WEB-INF/views/jsp/. Include the leading /.